# Disable selected choices in angular-ui-select multiselect mode

Tags: angularjs, select, multiple-select, ui-select, angular-ui-select

In `ui-select` muliple mode, selected choices are removed(checked in source code too) from the choices list but I just need that selected choices to be disabled, like below, instead of being removed.

[image]

this above image is taken from [chosenjs](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#selected-and-disabled-support).

There is an option, `ui-disable-choice`, to disable the choices but it just make the choice entirely unselectable.

```
<ui-select-choices ui-disable-choice="person.name=='Adam'" repeat="person in people">
  <div ng-bind-html="person.name"></div>
</ui-select-choices>
```

So, How to make the selected choices to appear in the choices but disabled?

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0j3uBU5WyKNPp9Aq1U6R?p=preview) example here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you are asking for is available in `ui-select` v0.17.2 or later.
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/ui-select#examples-disabling-instead-of-removing-selected-items-in-multiple-selection